# Button will not appear or will disappear after being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following part of code:

```
<div id="code" class="bg-primary">

            <div class="code-output">rgb(0,0,0);<div class="btn btn-warning pull-right" id="reset">Reset</div></div>    

        </div>
```

The problem is that the button with id="reset" will not appear at all sometimes or will disappear after clicking it.Any ideas?Here is my css and some js:
CSS

```
#reset{
    position: relative;
bottom: 0.56em;
left: 0.5em;
}
```

JS

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
        $('.rgb').val(0);
        color="rgb(0,0,0)";
        $(".code-output").html(color+";");
        $("#rgbaOutput").css("background","black");
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to close div for your code output before you declare your button, otherwise calling html() method will erase your button.

Also notice my JavaScript Tweaks - don't use variable before you declare it - because it will go to the global object (talking about **color** var).

Extra advices: Try to be consistent using quotations. Try to be consistent about code indentation. Also, put a space around operators. All those small details improve readability of your code.

(I am ignoring that there's jQuery statements that don't do anything in the example code, assuming that it would do something in your full context)

```js
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
  var color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  
  $(".rgb").val(0);      
  $(".code-output").html(color + ";");
  $("#rgbaOutput").css("background", "black");
});
```

```css
#reset {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0.56em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="code" class="bg-primary">

  <div class="code-output">rgb(0,0,0);</div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning pull-right" id="reset">Reset</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices.color is a variable i have declared in other part of my code(that's not the whole code).What's the difference between .click() and .on("click",function(){}); ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you say this:

`$(".code-output").html(color+";");`

Which will replace everything in the `<div class=".code-output">` and make the rgb value appear.

Because your reset div is inside this div, it will disappear (obviously).

Just use this instead:

```
<div class="code-output">rgb(0,0,0);</div> <!-- use </div> tag here -->
<div class="btn btn-warning pull-right" id="reset">Reset</div> <!-- instead of here -->
```